# Passing a column name for a new column in a function without tidyeval?

Tags: r, function, rename, tidyeval

I have worked a solution to this problem with `tidyeval`, is there a base R method?

```r
library(dplyr)

new_col <- function(df, col_name, col_vals){
  df |>
    cbind(temp_name = col_vals) |>
    rename({{col_name}} := temp_name)
}

sleep %>% 
  new_col(sample, "sample1") |>
  new_col(condition, "condition2") |>
  head()
#>   extra group ID  sample  condition
#> 1   0.7     1  1 sample1 condition2
#> 2  -1.6     1  2 sample1 condition2
#> 3  -0.2     1  3 sample1 condition2
#> 4  -1.2     1  4 sample1 condition2
#> 5  -0.1     1  5 sample1 condition2
#> 6   3.4     1  6 sample1 condition2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

This seems indirect and depends on `tidyeval` concepts that are less known. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59491021/passing-in-column-name-as-argument) also uses `{{}}` and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43641851/passing-a-variable-for-a-column-name) uses `enquo()`. My solution also needs `:=`.

Ideally, I want to map vectors of metadata (say, in a dataframe) to a matching list of dataframes/objects.

Comment: NSE is less known. It you are using dplyr and implementing NSE, I would argue that tidyeval should then be used. That's the whole point.

Comment: Note that tidyverse functions generally use NSE for referring to _existing_ columns, not for creating new ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `base R`, we can use `deparse/substitute`

```
new_col <- function(df, col_name, col_vals){
  cn <- deparse(substitute(col_name))
  df[[cn]] <- col_vals  
   df
}
```

-testing

```
 sleep %>% 
+   new_col(sample, "sample1") |>
+   new_col(condition, "condition2") |>
+   head()
  extra group ID  sample  condition
1   0.7     1  1 sample1 condition2
2  -1.6     1  2 sample1 condition2
3  -0.2     1  3 sample1 condition2
4  -1.2     1  4 sample1 condition2
5  -0.1     1  5 sample1 condition2
6   3.4     1  6 sample1 condition2
```